# Multiple managed packages with the same namespace (first gen)

Tags: managed-package, namespace

I've created two managed packages using the second gen process but they can't currently be submitted for appexchange review. I'm in the midst of downgrading the packaging process - the documentation seems to state that a packaging org needs to be created with a unique namespace and only one managed package can be associated with the packaging org.

Is it possible to have two managed packages with the same namespace in first gen packaging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You can have only one managed package per developer org. That precludes your scenario.

Here's the discussion on Idea Exchange: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqDaAAK

Comment: Cool, thanks for confirming my suspicions. Hopefully they push gen2 managed packages to GA soon.